OpenAI Assistants API: Is there an API endpoint to list all existing thread IDs?
What is a workaround to list all thread IDs from the OpenAI developer platform (https://platform.openai.com/threads/) using JavaScript?
There is no official API to list all available threads.
I found answers about the v1 API. It's also possible to list messages for a given thread, but that's not what is needed.
Sources:

https://community.openai.com/t/where-can-i-see-all-the-threads-ive-created-with-the-api/592963
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/threads
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/messages/listMessages


Did you try https://api.openai.com/v1/threads?

If try https://api.openai.com/v1/threads - response: {  "error": { "message": "Missing bearer or basic authentication in header", "type":"invalid_request_error", "param": null,"code": null}}

I obviously meant trying it with your credentials or API client, not just in the browser.

There are no endpoint to list thread IDs.

I also tried curl https://api.openai.com/v1/threads -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" -H "OpenAI-Beta: assistants=v1" Response: "error": {
"message": "Your request to GET /v1/threads must be made with a session key (that is, it can only be made from the browser). You made it with the following key type: secret.",..}

After long day searching, found a way to get a list of all threads available on OpenAI developer platform dashboard threads page (https://platform.openai.com/threads).

Go to threads page (must be logged in).
Open Developer Tools inside browser.
Paste js code in console

const html = document.body.innerHTML;
const threadIdRegex = /thread_[A-Za-z0-9]+/g; // Regular expression to match thread IDs
const threadIds = html.match(threadIdRegex) || [];
const threadIdsSet = new Set(threadIds);

console.log(threadIdsSet);

Now you have a list of all threads that you can use further in your application.
Example use. WARNING! All data would be deleted, use with caution!
Delete all threads on OpenAI threads page:
const = ['thread_123...', ...]

for (const threadId of threadList) {
  openai.beta.threads.del(threadId)
}


No, you cannot list an existing thread via the Assistants API if you didn't store the thread ID when creating it.
You can:

Create a thread
Retrieve a thread (assuming you have the thread ID stored)
Modify a thread
Delete a thread

The https://api.openai.com/v1/threads API endpoint suggested in the comment above is to create a thread.
Also, retrieving a thread is not what you're looking for because you need to pass the thread ID to the API endpoint. There's no way to list existing thread IDs via the Assistants API.

My question was redacted i didn't asked about Assistant API, I asked about workround, and seems I found something.
